# how to new bean of a class in some jar like hashMap by using annotaton instead of xml

Tags: spring, annotations, spring-annotations

in xml

```
<!-- 消息type和实现类的对应关系 -->
<bean id="handlerMapping" class="java.util.HashMap">
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="${sme.activemq.typeName.filter}">
                <ref bean="smeMessageHandler" />
            </entry>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

but how to new/create bean  of a class in some jar(  example : hashMap )  by using annotaton instead of xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method to find answer is more important.

Use google.com to search " spring create bean annotation ".

The first and the second also tell you the [answer](http://static.springsource.org/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html).

Or you can look for the official document in the Spring official site.

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

   @Bean
   public Map<String, smeMessageHandlerClass> handlerMapping() {
   Map<String,Object>  map=new HashMap<String,smeMessageHandlerClass >();
 map.put( key,smeMessageHandler());
 return handlerMapping;
  }
@Bean 
public smeMessageHandlerClass smeMessageHandler() {
  return new smeMessageHandlerClass ();
 }

 @config("sme.activemq.typeName.filter")
 public String key;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Annotation config can work as such

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

   @Bean
   public Map<String,Object> handlerMapping() {
     //define your map
     //return it
     return handlerMapping;
   }

}
```

have a look at [the docs here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-framework/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java) to give a better overview